# Firefox os Gaia on osx 10.5.8 make error

Tags: git, gaia, firefox-os

I try to install Gaia using mozilla [instructions](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gaia/Hacking)

OSX : 10.5.8
Xcode : 3.1.4
Git : git-1.7.5.4-i386-leopard

```
$ cd ~/ffos/
$ git clone git://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia.git gaia
Cloning into gaia...
remote: Counting objects: 110061, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (31997/31997), done.
remote: Total 110061 (delta 78367), reused 106338 (delta 75377)
Receiving objects: 100% (110061/110061), 294.06 MiB | 846 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (78367/78367), done.
$ cd gaia/
$ DEBUG=1 make
rm -rf xulrunner-sdk /usr/bin/curl -O http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/nightly/2012/09/2012-09-20-03-05-43-mozilla-central/xulrunner-18.0a1.en-US.mac-x86_64.sdk.tar.bz2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 54.2M  100 54.2M    0     0   527k      0  0:01:45  0:01:45 --:--:--  590k
tar xjf xulrunner*.tar.bz2 && rm xulrunner*.tar.bz2
test -d profile || mkdir -p profile
run-js-command  applications-data
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
/bin/bash: line 1:   439 Trace/BPT trap          ./xulrunner-sdk/bin/run-mozilla.sh ./xulrunner-sdk/bin/xpcshell -e "$JS_CONSTS" -f build/utils.js "build/applications-data.js"
make: *** [applications-data] Error 133
```

i found this article, but it's the same :
http://sebastian.germes.in/blog/2012/04/dyld-unknown-required-load-command-0x80000022-tracebpt-trap/

if someone have idea for my probleme.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) to run js commands ...